# Adding an image inside a RichTextBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I'm trying to add a static image inside a `RichTextBox` based on the selection of a ListBox item. I'm able to achieve the functionality of loading the image but the image doesn't occupy the entire size of the `RichTextBox`. I looked at MSDN documentation for any property I could set but couldn't find any that suits my need.

I've posted a sample code snippet to add an image to a `RichTextBox`.

```
<Window x:Class="ImageDepth.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <RichTextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" BorderBrush="Gray">
        <FlowDocument>
            <BlockUIContainer>
                <Image Source="C:\Temp\Penguins.jpg"/>
            </BlockUIContainer>                
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
</Grid>
```

Am I missing something here or is there a simpler way to achieve this?

**Edit:** I tried setting the Height and Width of the Image to that of the `RichTextBox` but it covers about 80% of the `RichTextBox`. Also, I had to remove the Stretch property of the Image since it distorts the image slightly even though setting the property makes the image cover about 90% of the area.

Comment: Shouldn't you set the Width and Height of your Image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to bind **`Height`** and **`Width`** of Image to **`ActualHeight`** and **`ActualWidth`** of RichTextBox.

```
<Image Source="C:\Temp\Penguins.jpg"
       Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                               Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=RichTextBox}}"
       Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                             Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=RichTextBox}}"/>
```

---

**UPDATE**

There seems internal padding of RichTextBox. You can set that to negative value to remove that padding.

```
<RichTexBox Padding="-5,-2,-5,-2"> // It reads Left, Top, Right, Bottom
   ....
</RichTexBox>
```

*Change **-5,-2,-5,-2** to desired value which seems fit for you.*

Comment: This seems to be the best approach to try and get the image to cover the whole area of the RichTextBox but it somehow doesn't work as expected. Some amount of unfilled space still remains on all 4 sides of the RichTextBox even if I bind the Height and Width of the Image to the ActualHeight and ActualWidth of the RichTextBox or hard code the values.

Comment: There seems some internal padding of RichTextBox. You can overcome that by giving negative padding value. I have updated the answer. See if that helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<Window x:Class="ImageDepth.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <RichTextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" BorderBrush="Gray">
        <FlowDocument>
            <BlockUIContainer>
                <Image Height="100" Width="100" Source="C:\Temp\Penguins.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
            </BlockUIContainer>                
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
</Grid>
```

This will tell your image to fill the entire `RichTextBox`.

Comment: I did try adding both Height and Width of the image to match that of the RichTextBox but it still doesn't fill up the entire area of the RichTextBox. Of course, setting the Height and Width does make the image cover a larger area but not entirely.